# how to install Redis Desktop Manager on openSUSE?

Tags: redis

it's offical documents are old.

I am openSUSE TW.
I can not find qmake-qt5 package using 'zypper se'.
Building is diffcult for me. If provide a rpm, that is best choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can build [RedisDesktopManager from source on openSUSE](http://docs.redisdesktop.com/en/latest/install/#fedora-centos-opensuse):

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/uglide/RedisDesktopManager.git -b 0.9 rdm
cd ./rdm/src
./configure
qmake-qt5 && make && sudo make install
cd /usr/share/redis-desktop-manager/bin
sudo mv qt.conf qt.backup
```

Full disclosure: I'm developer of RedisDesktopManager